# Pygame update the score when enemies collide

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pygame

```
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(Enemy_List,Bullet_List,True,True,Score_Change())

def Score_Change():
    global Score
    Score += 1
    print(Score) #For testing purposes
```

This line makes two enemies who collide disappear. However the function at the end always is on for some reason and i want it to only come on when the enemies collide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime this line

```
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(Enemy_List,Bullet_List,True,True,Score_Change())
```

is executed, `Score_Change()` will be called, the code inside this function will be executed, and its return value (`None`), will be passed to the `groupcollide` function as `collided` argument.

Note that the last parameter expects a function that calculates if two sprites collide. From the documentation:

> The `collided` argument is a callback function used to calculate if two sprites are colliding. It should take two sprites as values and return a bool value indicating if they are colliding. If `collided` is not passed, then all sprites must have a “rect” value, which is a rectangle of the sprite area, which will be used to calculate the collision.

You usually pass a function like `pygame.sprite.collide_mask` or `pygame.sprite.collide_circle` as this argument.

So it seems you expect `Score_Change` to be called if a collision happens. That's not the case. What you could do is something like:

```
for k, v in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(Enemy_List,Bullet_List,True,True):
    # k is the enemy
    # v is a list of bullets that them
    global Score
    Score += 1
    print(Score)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide):

> groupcollide(group1, group2, dokill1, dokill2, collided = None) -> Sprite_dict
>
> The collided argument is a callback function used to calculate if two
> sprites are colliding. It should take two sprites as values and return
> a bool value indicating if they are colliding. If collided is not
> passed, then all sprites must have a “rect” value, which is a
> rectangle of the sprite area, which will be used to calculate the
> collision.

The function that you are passing `Score_Change` is being called to check if two units collide.

`groupcollide` returns a dictionary of elements that have collided. That could help you calculate the score by checking how many enemies have collided:

```
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(Enemy_List,Bullet_List,True,True)
increment_score(len(collisions))

def increment_score(amount = 1):
    global Score
    Score += amount
    print(Score) #For testing purposes
```

PS: this function does not handle the removal of the two enemies that collide